# Trying to pull web data with Alamofire (Json)

Tags: ios, json, alamofire

I'm trying to pull web data to be placed in a tableview and custom cell in Swift.

My app dies at

```
if let tmpdata = response.data {
                for entry in tmpdata.valueForKey("results") as! [NSDictionary] {
                    let musicTrack = MusicTrack(data: entry)
                    self.musicTracks.append(musicTrack)
                }
```

Heres The code for my Music Manager.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

let musicUrl = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=one%20republic"

class MusicManager {
    var musicTracks: [MusicTrack] = []
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    func getMusicTracks(onComplete : (results :[MusicTrack]) -> Void) {

        Alamofire.request(.GET, musicUrl).responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")

            if let tmpdata = response.data {
                for entry in tmpdata.valueForKey("results") as! [NSDictionary] {
                    let musicTrack = MusicTrack(data: entry)
                    self.musicTracks.append(musicTrack)
                }
                onComplete(results: self.musicTracks)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then my ListViewController

```
import UIKit

class ListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    let musicManager = MusicManager()
    var musicTracks: [MusicTrack]!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        musicManager.getMusicTracks { (results) -> Void in
            self.musicTracks = results
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

            func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
                return 1
            }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(self.musicTracks != nil){
    return self.musicTracks.count
    }
    return 0
    }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell: MusicCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("musicCell") as! MusicCell
                cell.posterImage.image = nil
                let mTrack = self.musicTracks[indexPath.row]
                let imagedata = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: mTrack.thumbnail)!)
                if let tmpdata = imagedata {
                    cell.posterImage.image = UIImage(data: tmpdata)
                }
                cell.artistName.text = mTrack.artistName
                cell.trackName.text = mTrack.trackName
                return cell
            }


}
```

The error I get back is

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key results.'

Any help or direction would be awesome.

Thank you!

Comment: i think the problem is in `[NSDictionary]`, it should be `[String:String]` or `[String:AnyValue]`

Answer (score 0):

```
I faced the similar problem to but i came up with a solution.

-> Add the below function to yourviewcontroller.swift file

func postWebserviceWithURL(strUrl: String, param: NSDictionary?, completionHandler: (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> ()) -> (){
        Alamofire.request(.POST, strUrl, parameters: param as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL).responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {

            case .Success(let data):
                let json = data as? NSDictionary
                completionHandler(json, nil)

            case .Failure(let error):
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }

-> then for calling the func/api, use below code

self.postWebserviceWithURL("passyourURL", param: parameters) { (response, error) -> () in

                if error == nil{
                    print("success")
                }
                else {
                       print("failed")
                }
             }
             else{
print("error")
              }
            }
```